# how to make some textbox next to each other in j2me

Tags: java, java-me

i'm working on a j2me project with java wireless toolkit and i need to make 4 textbox next to each other.
i used these for:

```
private TextField emailTxt;
private TextField passwordTxt;
private TextField nameTxt;
private TextField mobileTxt;
private TextField urlTxt; 

public UserRegistrationMIDlet() {
    emailTxt = new TextField("pelak:\n", "", 2, TextField.EMAILADDR);
    passwordTxt = new TextField("", "", 1, TextField.PASSWORD);
    nameTxt = new TextField("", "", 3, TextField.ANY);
    mobileTxt = new TextField("", "", 2, TextField.PHONENUMBER);
    urlTxt = new TextField("address:", "", 100, TextField.URL);
```

}

but j2me textboxes and textfields, every one fill a line and become under each other.
as i searched for i understood the Textbox has no set location method but isn't there any other way to make them just next to each other?
f.n: some one said that it's possible with changing the margins?! how?!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are adding these `TextField` to a `Form`, so, according to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Form.html#layout):

> Layout policy in Form is organized around rows. Rows are typically
>   related to the width of the screen, respective of margins, scroll
>   bars, and such. All rows in a particular Form will have the same
>   width. Rows do not vary in width based on the Items contained within
>   the Form, although they may all change width in certain circumstances,
>   such as when a scroll bar needs to be added or removed. Forms
>   generally do not scroll horizontally.

But you play with [`setLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Item.html#setLayout(int)). For example:

```
emailTxt.setLayout(Item.LAYOUT_2 | Item.LAYOUT_SHRINK);
passwordTxt.setLayout(Item.LAYOUT_2 | Item.LAYOUT_SHRINK);
nameTxt.setLayout(Item.LAYOUT_2 | Item.LAYOUT_SHRINK);
mobileTxt.setLayout(Item.LAYOUT_2 | Item.LAYOUT_SHRINK);
urlTxt.setLayout(Item.LAYOUT_2 | Item.LAYOUT_SHRINK);
```

As a last resort you can build your own input field extending from [CustomItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/CustomItem.html) and have all your fields merged into one.